# React Native: PanResponder with text selection

Tags: react-native, drag, panresponder

Dragging not always working if something else is selected on the screen. For a Web page specifically, in [this example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder#example) if part of the "Drag this box title" selected, the box is not draggable as the browser tries to drag the selected text instead. Is there any workaround to avoid this?

[image]